# Elixir - Assigning the result of a complex if statement to a variable

Tags: elixir

How would I make `error` variable always equal to a string? It is nil in almost all scenarios, and never should be nil. In all the scenarios where I have a string, I want to make `error` equal to that string:

```
error = if user_product do
      if user_product.voted_not_vegan && report do
        "Whoops! You have already reported this product is not vegan"
      end

      if !user_product.voted_not_vegan && report do
        changeset =
        UserProduct.changeset(
          user_product,
          %{:voted_not_vegan => true}
        )
        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> IO.puts("error")
          {:error, changeset} -> IO.puts("error")
        end

        "Success! Reported not vegan"
        changeset =
        Product.changeset(
          product,
          %{:not_vegan_count => not_vegan_count + 1}
        )

        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> IO.puts("error")
          {:error, changeset} -> IO.puts("error")
        end
      end

      IO.inspect(user_product, label: "userproduct")
      IO.inspect(confirm, label: "confirm")

      if user_product.voted_vegan && confirm do
        "Whoops! You have already confirmed this product is vegan"
      end

      if !user_product.voted_vegan && confirm do
        changeset =
        Product.changeset(
          product,
          %{:vegan_count => vegan_count + 1}
        )


        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product_shop} -> IO.puts("error")
          {:error, changeset} -> IO.puts("error")
        end


        "Success! Confirmed is vegan"

        changeset =
        UserProduct.changeset(
          user_product,
          %{:voted_vegan => true}
        )

        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> IO.puts("error")
          {:error, changeset} -> IO.puts("error")
        end
      end
    else
      IO.puts("insert user product")
      UserProduct.insert_user_product(conn, %{
        p_id: String.to_integer(pid),
        u_id: uid,
        voted_not_vegan: report,
        voted_vegan: confirm
      })

      user_product =
      from(up in UserProduct,
        where: up.u_id == ^uid,
        where: up.p_id == ^pid
      )
      |> Api.Repo.one()

      if report do
        changeset =
        Product.changeset(
          product,
          %{:not_vegan_count => not_vegan_count + 1}
        )
        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> IO.puts("error")
          {:error, changeset} -> IO.puts("error")
        end

        changeset =
        UserProduct.changeset(
          user_product,
          %{:voted_not_vegan => true}
        )

        case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
          {:ok, product} -> IO.puts("error")
          {:error, changeset} -> IO.puts("error")
        end

        "Success! Reported not vegan"

      end
```

Below is my implementation of @Aleksei Matiushkin's answer. It seems to be working, although may have deviated from the answer.

```
  @spec check_user_product(
          usr_prduct :: %UserProduct{},
          {report :: boolean(), confirm :: boolean()},
          product :: %Product{}
        ) :: any()
  defp check_user_product(user_product, report_confirm, product)

  @doc """
    User confirms product is vegan, when they have already done so.
  """
  defp check_user_product(
         %UserProduct{voted_vegan: true} = _usr_prduct,
         {_, true} = _report_confirm,
         _product
       ) do
    "Whoops! You have already confirmed this product is vegan"
  end

  @doc """
    User confirms product is vegan, when they have not already done so.
  """
  defp check_user_product(
         %UserProduct{voted_vegan: false} = usr_prduct,
         {_, true} = _report_confirm,
         product
       ) do
    changeset =
      Product.changeset(
        product,
        %{:vegan_count => product.vegan_count + 1}
      )

    case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
      {:error, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
    end

    changeset =
      UserProduct.changeset(
        usr_prduct,
        %{:voted_vegan => true}
      )

    case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
      {:error, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
    end

    "Success! Confirmed is vegan"
  end

  @doc """
    User reports product is not vegan, when they have already done so.
  """
  defp check_user_product(
         %UserProduct{voted_not_vegan: true} = _usr_prduct,
         {true, _} = _report_confirm,
         _product
       ),
       do: "Whoops! You have already reported this product is not vegan"

  @doc """
    User reports product is not vegan, when they haven't already done so.
  """
  defp check_user_product(
         %UserProduct{voted_not_vegan: false} = usr_prduct,
         {true, _} = _report_confirm,
         product
       ) do
    changeset =
      UserProduct.changeset(
        usr_prduct,
        %{:voted_not_vegan => true}
      )

    case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
      {:error, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
    end

    changeset =
      Product.changeset(
        product,
        %{:not_vegan_count => product.not_vegan_count + 1}
      )

    case Api.Repo.update(changeset) do
      {:ok, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
      {:error, _} -> IO.puts("filler")
    end

    "Success! Reported not vegan"
  end

  def put_product_is_vegan(conn) do
    product = Api.Product |> Api.Repo.get(conn.query_params["p_id"])
    confirm = parse_elem(conn.body_params["confirm"])
    report = parse_elem(conn.body_params["report"])
    uid = conn.query_params["u_id"]
    pid = conn.query_params["p_id"]

    user_product =
      from(usr_prduct in Api.UserProduct,
        where: usr_prduct.u_id == ^uid,
        where: usr_prduct.p_id == ^pid
      )
      |> Api.Repo.one()

    user_product =
      if !user_product do
        UserProduct.insert_user_product(conn, %{
          p_id: String.to_integer(pid),
          u_id: uid,
          voted_not_vegan: false,
          voted_vegan: false
        })

        user_product =
          from(usr_prduct in UserProduct,
            where: usr_prduct.u_id == ^uid,
            where: usr_prduct.p_id == ^pid
          )
          |> Api.Repo.one()

        user_product
      else
        user_product
      end

    error = check_user_product(user_product, {report, confirm}, product)

    product = Api.Repo.get_by(Product, id: pid)

    IO.inspect(error, label: "errors")

    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("application/json")
    |> send_resp(
      200,
      Poison.encode!(%{
        successs: "success",
        product: product,
        errors: error
      })
    )
  end
```

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `%{:not_vegan_count => product.not_vegan_count + 1}` is idiomatically written as `%{not_vegan_count: product.not_vegan_count + 1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb would be you try to strictly avoid using nested `if` conditional statement in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir). It’s extremely counter-idiomatic and code smell in general.

There are tons of better ways to handle every problem: function clauses, patter-matching, [`with/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html?#with/1), etc.

Here the most applicable way to solve the issue would be to stick to splitting the conditional into a set of function clauses with pattern matching. Somewhat alongside lines below would work.

```rb
error = check_user_product(user_product, {report, config})

@spec check_user_product(
        up :: %UserProduct{},
        {report :: boolean(), config :: boolean()},
        stage :: :checking_not | :checking_yes
      ) :: any()
defp check_user_product(up, rc, stage \\ :checking_not)

defp check_user_product(
      %UserProduct{voted_not_vegan: true} = up,
      {false, _} = rc,
      :checking_not),
  do: check_user_product(up, rc, :checking_yes)

defp check_user_product(
      %UserProduct{voted_not_vegan: true} = up,
      {true, _},
      :checking_not),
  do: "Whoops! You have already reported this product is not vegan"

defp check_user_product(
      %UserProduct{} = up,
      {true, _},
      :checking_not),
  do: changeset = [...]

defp check_user_product(
      %UserProduct{voted_vegan: true} = up,
      {_, true},
      :checking_yes),
  do: "Whoops! You have already reported this product is vegan"

defp check_user_product(%UserProduct{} = up, _, :checking_yes),
  do: changeset = [...]

defp check_user_product(_, _, _),
  do: "Whoops! No UserProduct"
```

Here we pattern match against `%UserProduct{}` to pattern-match by voting and either return immediately or continue to the next check.

Just imagine the input *and* follow the pattern-matching path if unsure.

Nested conditional `if`s are pure evil.

---

You might avoid the need in the second parameter at all, by pattern-matching directly to both `voted_vegan` and `voted_not_vegan`, but this requires additional knowledge of the business domain, so I would leave this as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently trying to implement this. I have posted my current attempt in the bottom of my question. I have the error: `only variables and \\ are allowed as arguments in function head` on this line `defp check_user_product(%UserProduct{}, report_confirm, stage \\ :checking_not)`. What is the `stage/:checking_not` referring to here? `stage :: :checking_not | :checking_yes`?

Comment: Ouch, sorry, updated. It should be `defp check_user_product(up, rc, stage \\ :checking_not)`. Stage is, well, the stage. You were checking `voted_not_vegan` and _then_ `voted_vegan` in stages; first, then second. This is needed for proper routing between clauses to know what to be validated, `report`, or `confirm`.

Comment: Thank you! I have now got it fully working. I have put my implementation at the bottom of my question. It differs from yours slightly but I believe it uses the same main idea. I wasn' t wrapping my brain around the `stage` and did it by checking only the first and second params. My third param was used to do database insertions. My main bit of ugly code is where I make sure user_product is assigned a value inside `put_product_is_vegan(conn)`. If you see a nicer way I'd appreciate it if you'd let me know.. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, seems fine. I have introduced stages only to _fully replicate_ the behaviour you’ve introduced in the original question. It surely seems to be redundant, so kudos for getting rid of it. The only improvement I can think of is mentioned in the last sentence of my answer: you might want to try to match _both_ `vegan` and `not_vegan` votes in the same clause to early rule out inconsistencies like`check(%UserProduct{voted_not_vegan: true, voted_vegan: true}, _, _), do: "Cannot be both vegan and not vegan"`, but I am not sure if it’s worth it.

Comment: The main advice you should probably listen to would be _if you find yourself doing many `if`’s, you are likely attempting it wrong_. [tag:elixir] has a lot of fancy ways to handle it better. The code without conditional statements is always simpler, more succinct and easier to reason about.

Answer (score -1):

Every possible control flow must return a string:

```
error =
      if true do
        if !false and true do
          "!false and true"
        else
          "2nd else case"
        end
      else
        "1st else case"
      end
"!false and true"
```